# 20 blue balls and 11 yellow, drawing 6 times with no replacement, what is the chance that at least one is yellow OR the first two draws are the same?

Tags: probability

> 20 blue balls and 11 yellow, drawing 6 times with no replacement, what is the chance that at least one is yellow OR the first two draws are the same?

I'm not sure my intuition for the solution of the problem is correct, in particular, I have some issue with the addition rule part.

I started out this problem by thinking about the two scenarios:

1) the first two are yellow

2) the first two are blue

I'm a bit confused about the first scenario: P(at least 1 yellow) OR P(first two are the same) if the first two are yellow, that also satisfy the P(at least 1 yellow) so in this case does the probability equal to 1?

Is this similar to flipping a coin P(head) or P(tail)? Or perhaps it's only a "double counted intersection" that we have to subtract out?

I also thought about using compliment to solve this problem but I'm not quite sure if it works this way:

1-  [P(no yellow) or P(first two are different)]

thank you!

Comment: Is it a success if both conditions hold?  If so, then the answer is $1$ (if there are no yellows drawn then every draw is blue, so, in particular, the first two draws are blue).

Comment: If the first two draws are not the same then there will be at least one yellow

Comment: OHHHHHH, I get it now, because we only have 2 types of balls to draw from. No matter what we draw we always satisfy at least 1 of the 2 conditions thus the probability is 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR in mathematics is the inclusive or, so if either condition or both is satisfied the sentence is satisfied.  OR in English is ambiguous, it can be inclusive or exclusive.  Given the problem, I would take it as inclusive here.  As you say, that makes the probability $1$.  Either the first two balls are blue and hence the same color or at least one of them is yellow.  We win either way.